# How to find rare codons in a given sequence?

Tags: bioinformatics

What is the concept behind writing a program to find out rare codons in a list of sequences? I'm not asking the codings from anyone. Just want to know the concept.

Comment: I think http://biostar.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for your question.

Comment: I think, this is just like searching a substring in the string. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

here's some python for you:

```
codon = "TAG"

sequence = "AAAAAAAAAATAG"
if sequence.find(codon) != -1:
    #found codon in the string!
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for patterns inside strings is the very reason-of-existence of loved loved and feared Regular Expressions.

These are expressions full of symbols which represent string patterns. With an appropriately built regular expression, you can search a text for any sub-text that "matches" the regular expression. This can allow you to find very complex patterns and perform a lot of operations like splitting, replacing, etc.

Hope this helps.